# Angular 2 getting started tutorial magically generates data

Tags: angular

I'm currently developing the Angular 2 Getting Started Tutorial. I'm in the [last chapter called "HTTP"](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html). I just learned how to add a data set to a list of sets. It basically shows how to "POST" things into the backend API.

I've created a mock service to simulate a real HTTP backend:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let heroes = [
      {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
      {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
      {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
      {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
      {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
      {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
      {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
      {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
      {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
      {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'}
    ];
    return { heroes };
  }
}
```

Also there is a service which fiddles with this data:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import {Hero} from "./hero";

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  update(hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
    return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers}).toPromise().then(() => hero).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
      .toPromise().then(response => response.json().data as Hero[]).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

  getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.http.post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers}).toPromise().then(res => res.json().data).catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

The add method which is called by the click listener of the UI button looks like this:

```
  add(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }
    this.heroService.create(name).then(hero => { this.heroes.push(hero); this.selectedHero = null;});
  }
```

You can easily play around with a similar state of this app [here](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/eplnkr.html).

You add something in an input box and click "Save". The click listener calls "add()" and add the service's "create()" where lastly a web-service gets called. The newly created data set gets added to the list and is actually part of the mock-data. It is stored with the given name (originating from the input web-component) and the appropriated number (if the last hero was 20, you get 21) stored as "id".

This code leaves me absolutely baffled. I can't get my head around the fact that it works. Why would this mock API now what to do just because it gets a name? I mean you *post* something to the API providing a name. Fine. But how in the world would it know that there is another property "id" which needs to be auto-incremented?

Just to show it isolated from the other boilerplate, this is the code snippet I'm talking about:

```
http.post('api/heroes', JSON.stringify({name: name}), new Headers({Content-Type: 'application/json'});
```

Comment: Well, because it's implemented this way: when it receives a new name, it finds the max ID, increments it, and adds the new hero to its list. See https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/in-memory-backend.service.js#L494 and https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/in-memory-backend.service.js#L382

Comment: @JBNizet Oh well ... :D

Comment: @JBNizet This means if I use a mock service and have a property called id everything is done by InMemoryDbService already? I just need to provide the proper values for the other properties, don't I? Is this also true if I either don't have any data from scratch or my data doesn't have the property "id" yet?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You're using a very specific in-memory database service that is specifically written to illustrate, in the angular documentation, how you would interact with a real RESTful backend allowing to list and create heroes. To ease with the experimentation, it's in-memory rather than being a real, networked backend, but it has nothing generic, and simply allows you to create new heroe, and generates IDs for these new heroes, just like a real RESTful service would do (using a database sequence for example).

Comment: This InMemoryDbService should never be used by anything else than this specific documentation demo.

Answer (score 0):

The magic comes from the app.module using

`InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {delay: 200})`

if you drill into the module it returns an XHRBackend, which takes the xhr requests you're making and passes them to the in memory db.

`export declare function inMemoryBackendServiceFactory(injector: Injector, dbService: InMemoryDbService, options: InMemoryBackendConfig): XHRBackend;`